# Need help finding datasheet

Tags: capacitor, diodes, datasheet, identification, tvs

I have tried searching multiple sites such as digikey, google, bing, even wikipedia for the data sheets of the following Items but can not find them
these components are from a seagate barracuda.

Diodes (Most likely TVS Diodes)

[image: diode1]
[image: diode2]

Capacitor (I think)

[image]

Comment: At least you have good pictures...

Comment: @Fake What do you mean by "at least..."?

Comment: Trying to identify largely non-descript components is a crapshoot at best. We get questions like yours regularly, and you have by far the best pictures I have seen out of any of them.

Comment: @fake oh thank you I made these photos using a microscope :)

Comment: I figured that from the indicating pointer in the frame. Some of the scopes at my work have that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those look like short code numbers.  The full part number doesn't fit on small parts like this, so the manufacturer writes short codes.  For example, some MMBT4401 transistors I have are only labeled "2X".

In the datasheet for the part it tells you what variants have what codes, but going the other way is nearly impossible without a pretty good idea what the part already is.  If you know the manufacturer you can dig around their datasheets for parts of this class and hope to find one that lists the short code you see.

You might get lucky with some careful google searches using the code you have in quotes, with "SMD code", or "package code", along with "transistor" or whatever you think the device is.

Comment: I am pretty sure the diodes are tvs diodes

Comment: and the bottom looks like a smd polystyrene capacitor

Comment: maybe I can call Seagate and see what they are...

Comment: I will research the part list datasheets tomorrow and post what each part is. Thanks Olin :)